# Array under another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is probably a fairly simple way to do it, but I ask since I did not find it on google.

What I want is to add an array under another.

```
var array = [];

array[0]["username"] = "Eric";
array[0]["album"] = "1";
```

Something like this, I get no errors in Firebug, it does not work.
So my question is, how does one do this in javascript?

Comment: you should NOT use array as variable name since it can be confused with the Array object.

Comment: Javascript IS case sensitive.

Comment: it is, but well, it wasn't an answer, rather an advice.

Comment: I only use "array" as a variable name, in this example here =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var a= [
 { username: 'eric', album: '1'},
 { username: 'bill', album: '3'}
];
```

Comment: thx a lot! men vist du da ønsker å legge til flere i arrayet i ettertid da? I mitt tilfellet er det en loop

Comment: I'm so sorry, was so happy for your reply, I wrote it in my language. What I would say is: thx a lot! but shown when you want to add more in the array later then? In my case it is a loop

Comment: var a = [];

a.push({username: "foo", album: "3"})

Comment: This is an array that contains objects.  He wants an array that contains arrays.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
array[0] = new Array(2);
array[1] = new Array(5);
```

More about 2D array [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/twoarray1.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You should get an error in Firebug saying that array[0] is undefined (at least, I do).

Using string as keys is only possible with hash tables (a.k.a. objects) in Javascript.

Try this:

```
var array = [];
array[0] = {};
array[0]["username"] = "Eric";
array[0]["album"] = "1";
```

or

```
var array = [];
array[0] = {};
array[0].username = "Eric";
array[0].album = "1";
```

or simpler

```
var array = [];
array[0] = { username: "Eric", album: "1" };
```

or event simpler

```
var array = [{ username: "Eric", album: "1" }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Decompose.

```
var foo = new Array();
foo[0] = {};
foo[0]['username'] = 'Eric';
foo[0]['album'] = '1';
```